# Finding Poisson Critical Region with Casio CG-50

Tags: calculator

I am trying to figure out how to get the critical region for a Poisson distribution on a CG-50. On the classwiz, you could enter desired values into a table and the poisson value would be returned on another column (when you specific lambda). This was done by going Menu-> Distribution-> Page down-> Poisson CD-> List-> enter values into x-> = -> enter lambda-> = -> probabilities returned on p column. I am trying to get the cg-50 to return this kind of table so then the critical region at a particular significance level can be found. For some reason, when I go to poisson c.d. and set data to "list" it asks for a U.list and and L.list which I assumed were a lower and upper list, however incorrect values were returned and also if the lists were different in size (or one was empty) it would give me a out of range error.

Just want to be able to replicate the functionality of the classwizz!

Comment: What do you call "critical region" for a Poi($\lambda$) random variable ?

Comment: the value of the test statistic that would lead you to rejecting your null hypothesis (at a certain significance level) this isn’t as important, i’m more just concerned about how to create a table for all the poisson values